# Losing jQuery item data on "move"

Tags: jquery

**In essence:** every time I clone items I lose the data() value for those items.

**The long story:** I have a three column table that is storing items dynamically entered from a JSON object. Each of these items has a data value set that I use.

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, null, function(data) {
   jsonData = data.items;
   for (var key in jsonData) {
     lZeroArray.each(function() {
       if ($.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(jsonData[key].name)) {
         $(this).data("L1", jsonData[key].L1);
       }
     });
   };
 });
```

there is a click event on these items that uses the JSON data stored as the "L1" key and these work fine but ...

I allow these items to be filtered using a text box and the ":not(:contains('text'))" selector.

```
$(".subMenuItem:not(:contains('" + str + "'))").remove();
```

but ... because I have three columns the columns can be uneven so I attempt to resort the items into the three columns by cloning the remaining ones.

```
var items = $(".subMenuItem").clone(true);
$("#subMenuContent td").empty();
addItemsToColumn(items);
```

After I do this the click functions no longer find any of the data() values even though they workled before.

```
$(".subMenuItem").live("click", function() {
  if ($(this).data("L1")) {
    buildSubMenuItems($(this).data("L1"));
  }
});
```

How do I retain the data() values that I store with an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's clone method explicitly removes the data() values from the cloned elements (line 301 of jQuery v1.3.1):

```
        // Need to set the expando to null on the cloned set if it exists
        // removeData doesn't work here, IE removes it from the original as well
        // this is primarily for IE but the data expando shouldn't be copied over in any browser
        var clone = ret.find("*").andSelf().each(function(){
            if ( this[ expando ] !== undefined )
                this[ expando ] = null;
        });
```

You'll need grab the data then re-add it to the cloned elements.  jQuery's expando property name is not a public variable.

Comment: Here is an example of how you might copy over the data:

    var data = $.map( $(".subMenuItem"), function(elem) {
     return $(elem).data('L1')
    } );
    var items = $(".subMenuItem").clone(true).each(function(i) {
     $(this).data('L1', data[i])
    });
    $("#subMenuContent td").empty();
    addItemsToColumn(items);

Comment: according to those comments IE removes the data from the original as well. Am I reading that right?